# C code to check null pointer from json calls

Tags: c, json

I am a JSON newbie. It seems to me that I ought to be checking for a NULL pointer returned from all of the calls to cJSON_GetObjectItem(). But if there are MANY items within the object, this checking  becomes quite verbose. Do I need to check for NULLs returned from this call, and if so, is there a better way to do it than shown below?

```
jsonPortArray = cJSON_GetObjectItem(jsonInput,"port");
if (jsonPortArray != NULL)
{
    for (portIndex = 0; portIndex < cJSON_GetArraySize(jsonPortArray); portIndex++)
    {
        jsonPort = cJSON_GetArrayItem(jsonPortArray, portIndex);
        if (jsonPort == 0)
            break;  // Bail out of loop if null ptr.

        // ******* Is this safe? I see this style a lot.
        port[portIndex].portNum = cJSON_GetObjectItem(jsonPort, "portNum")->valueint;
        port[portIndex].portDir = cJSON_GetObjectItem(jsonPort, "portDir")->valueint;
        port[portIndex].portType = cJSON_GetObjectItem(jsonPort, "portType")->valueint;

        /*
        I shortened the list of values to get, but there are MANY.
        */

        // ******* Or do I need to check NULLs for every item, like this?
        if ( cJSON_GetObjectItem(jsonPort, "portNum") != NULL)
        {
            port[portIndex].portNum = cJSON_GetObjectItem(jsonPort, "portNum")->valueint;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first make sure you use NULL not 0 when checking.  It's required in C.

But basically other than that, no.  You can't do anything else.  If you don't know if a value exists, you need to check before you use it.  JSON, being unstructured as it is, requires this when using a strongly typed language.  Java has the same "problem".

You can change your style to return values early to decrease indenting that makes code hard to read, but you need to check the return of your calls.

Comment: Okay. I do have to check for nulls. I guess I've just seen a lot of lax code that doesn't. Thx for clearing this up.

Answer (score 2):

You should check for NULL, that or expect your program to segfault on bad input.

You can make it less verbose however:

```
#define JSON_OBJECT_NOT_NULL(jsonThing, name) \
    (cJSON_GetObjectItem(jsonThing, name) != NULL ? \
    cJSON_GetObjectItem(jsonThing, name)->valueint : -1)

...
port[portIndex].portNum = JSON_OBJECT_NOT_NULL(jsonPort, "portNum");
```

Here I use a macro and the [inline if](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a#C) to either assign to the value of `->valueint` or `-1` if the return was `NULL`.

Please note that this behaviour isn't exactly the same as what you had, if the return is NULL, I'm setting the value to -1, you were taking no action in your example. If you set to -1, you do still have to later detect that it is the invalid -1 value.

Also, for readablity I broke the define into multiple lines, the `\` characters are escaping the newlines, so that means no spaces after the `\` characters, or, join it onto one line.

```
#define JSON_OBJECT_NOT_NULL(jsonThing, name) (cJSON_GetObjectItem(jsonThing, name) != NULL ? cJSON_GetObjectItem(jsonThing, name)->valueint : -1)
```

Comment: Thx. You have answered my question; I do have to check for NULLs. The macro won't quite work for me because I preload all values (like portNum) with defaults before calling cJSON_SetObjectItem. The -1 would destroy that.